# Integral type that acts like a native one without implicit conversions

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to implement a *perfect* Integral type without implicit conversions to its underlying type (only explicit ones), and am stumbling against the following:

```
std::array<Integral, 10>a{{...}};
Integral index{5};
a[index] = ...; //error: no implicit conversion between Integral and std::size_t
```

There is a similar problem with C arrays. AFAIK the problem is that `operator[]` expects a specific type. If your type does not match the expected one and is not implicitly convertible to it, the only solutions I can think of are an explicit cast, a getter, and a `get` function to be applied on the array.

Is it possible to achieve something similar to the `explicit operator bool` (i.e. to be implicitly convertible *under specific circumstances only*) but for the `operator[]` ?

Writing `a[static_cast<std::size_t>(index)]` kind of defeats the purpose of writing an Integral type.

Comment: [This proposal for opaque typedefs](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3515.pdf) might interest you. I don't think anyone has implemented it as an extension, though, so you might want to look at Boost's strong typedefs.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to achieve something similar to the `explicit operator bool` (i.e. to be implicitly convertible *under specific circumstances only*)

This is called a *contextual conversion to* `bool`, and is only supported for the `bool` type. So, no, it can't be done.

IMO, explicit conversion (*via* a member function like `Integral::get() const`) is the way to go. After all, unless you are trying to create a type that is literally useless, there are probably going to be some values your class can represent that can't be stored in an `int`, which means the conversion is going to have to fail by throwing an exception. Better to be explicit than implicit, then.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas:

a) You might implement an implicit conversion to size_t.  I believe that operator[] expects this type.  This would trap all the conversions which are not to size_t.

Note that such an explicit conversion could be used to trap the case where a negative index is being used.  A useful behavior.

b) You might overload operator[] to accept your integral type.  Of course this would be a pain because you'd have to do it for all the types.  But on the other hand, you might be able to implement index checking on containers - another useful feature.

c) you might look up "safe numerics" for some peripherally related ideas.

Robert Ramey

Comment: `std::size_t` is implicitly convertible to `int`, making it possible to convert `Integral` implicitly to `int`. You might be able to leverage template metaprogramming to disable that sort of multistage conversion.